# ember: cannot access model from service

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am working on a cart service that will be injected, and I am using ember-data to store the cart data (because I need to persist the cart to the back-end).

Naturally, within the service I need to create computed properties on the cart data so that I can provide sums of quantities and totals.

But I am having a really, *really* hard time accessing the 'cart' model from the store in order to do this.  Here's what I am *trying* to do:

```
export default Service.extend({

    store: inject.service(),

    cartObj: null, // set in init() so cart data can be used in computed properties

    init() {
        this._super(...arguments);

        // get cart model from store, set it to property on the service
        let cartObj = this.get('store').peekAll('cart').get('firstObject');
        set(this, 'cartObj', cartObj);
    },

    lineItems: computed('cartObj.cartitems.[]', function() {
        // cartitems is a collection stored in each cart object
        return get(this, 'cartObj.cartitems');
    }),
    total: computed.sum('itemPrices'), // cart total

...
```

No matter what I try in init(): `this.get('store').peekAll('cart').get('firstObject')` or `this.store.peekAll('cart').get('firstObject')` or variations of the same with `.objectAt(0)` ...nothing works.

I either get errors about "get" not being a function, or the `cartObj` assignment evaluates to `null`

EVEN THOUGH the model is there, with data in it:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very first time you are injecting `cart` service, it will create instance and it will call init method, you just need to ensure by that time store is already filled with `cart` model.
Or you can try with computed property,

```
cartObj: Ember.computed(function(){
 this.get('store').peekAll('cart').get('firstObject');
})
```

Comment: ah!  of course.  I had an instance-initializer for the cart.  duh! Thank you so much!